# update Readonly int array?

Tags: c#, .net, readonly, readonly-collection

In Classical sense Readonly objects can only be set in the constrcutor and cannot be modified later on. Why do readonly int arrays behave any different.

PS:I am aware of `Readonly` collections, I am just curious to know why is this allowed ?

```
class Class1
{
    public readonly int[] a;

    public Class1()
    {
        a = new int[3];
        a[0] = 1;
        a[1] = 2;
        a[2] = 3;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        a[0] = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about it? The `int` array isn't *immutable*, just *readonly*, which means it just can be assigned once (barring some magic tricks like reflection). Its contents, on the other hand, can change...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Readonly modifier is applied to *actual type it assigned to*. So in this case it assigned to an Array type instance, *but not to a elements present inside it*.

That's why, yes, you still able to change element value, but the code like

```
public void Update()
{
   a = new int[3];
}
```

will fail, as you're going to change Array type instance (and not its content)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

`readonly` makes the array immutable, not the array items. `readonly` means you can assign an array to an `a` field inline or in constructor only. But it does not prevent anyone to change the content of each array item.

Answer (score 0):

If you make this array content to be readonly do like this

```
public readonly int[] a;
ReadOnlyCollection<int> result = Array.AsReadOnly(a);
public Class1()
{
    a = new int[3];
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;
    a[2] = 3;

}

public void Update()
{
    result[0] = 10; // Compile Time Error Here
}
```